# Display result in opensearch with same city result only

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have list of school in opensearch. Issues currently I am facing If I search for school

Something like that all related to school delhi only not other city name.

"Delhi Public School Delhi"

It give me result for :-

1. North Delhi Public School, North Delhi
2. Delhi Public School  Bikaner
3. South Delhi Public School, South Delhi
4. Delhi Public School, Sirsa
5. Delhi Public School, Kanpur

But I want if search for "Delhi Public School Delhi" I should only get result for

1)Delhi Public School Delhi
2) South Delhi Public School, South Delhi
3) North Delhi Public School, North Delhi
4) Delhi Public School, East of kailash
list goes on...

working on nodejs, javascript-opensearch client

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.